# Why do we need the second definition below in a `simple-declaration`?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[*simple-declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration):
     *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list*<sub>*opt*</sub> `;`
     *attribute-specifier-seq* *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list* `;`                                          <====
     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *decl-specifier-seq* *ref-qualifier*<sub>*opt*</sub> `[`*identifier-list*`]`*initializer* `;`

Note that the *attribute-specifier-seq* is required in this definition. When does that happen?

Comment: _Note that the attribute-specifier-seq is required in this definition._ To me, it reads more like that _init-declarator-list_ is required in this definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that we want our grammar to accept:

```
DSS;
DSS IDL;
ASS DSS IDL;
```

(plus accept array forms, which this answer will not deal with any further)

but not

```
ASS DSS;
```

That is, if the *attribute-specifier*(s) are provided, the *init-declarator-list* becomes required.

The grammar productions as shown in the question provide for this and importantly only parse any legal *simple-declaration* one way.

Every declaration which does not have an *attribute-specifier-seq* is parsed using the first case.  Every declaration which does is parsed using the second case.  There's no overlap between the two cases.

If the second case were

> *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list* `;`

then the same inputs would be allowed, but the rules overlap -- inputs of the form `DSS IDL;` would match both the first and the second, creating an ambiguous parse.

Overlapping rules are not wanted.

There's more than one way to solve this with non-overlapping rules.  The following would also be ok:

> *decl-specifier-seq* `;`
>
> *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* *decl-specifier-seq* *init-declarator-list* `;`

In effect, this comes from the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#2-variable_map_examples) for the truth table for the implication operator (ASS provided implies IDL provided), which has three True cells in an L pattern.  One solution arises from using a vertical circle, the other solution arises from using a horizontal circle.

In digital logic, overlap prevents glitching (good!).  In language grammar, overlap produces parsing ambiguity (bad!).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you decomposite this or does just it sit like *bam* ? -  Personally, I had just started to look at it when you answered.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: A little analysis is required, but the intent (implement implication) follows pretty directly from asking what's different between the first two cases.  (1) The second case has a attribute-specifier-seq that the first doesn't.  (2) In the second case the init-declarator-list is not optional.  Ahh!  The presence of the attribute specifier(s) makes the init-declarator(s) mandatory.

Comment: I'm very happy to see that "_A little analysis is required_" :-)  Thanks!